# What's the best way to display (and print) rtf files

Tags: printing, file-conversion

My son gets his homework assignments online as rtf files. On his Macbook, they are automatically opened with textedit which won't display graphics and other elements correctly or at all. So, he will need to convert to pdf (or open with another app). What's the best and most MACcy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some background to this - [Why cannot Pages show pictures in .rtf files?](http://pagesfaq.blogspot.co.uk/2006/12/why-cannot-pages-show-pictures-in-rtf.html)
that Apple decided not to support pictures in rtf because of limitations in the format, but instead to opt to use rtfd format which supports them much better.

The 'fix' would appear to be [without investing in Microsoft Word] to use [NeoOffice](https://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) or [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org), both of which support embedded pictures in rtf files.

Comment: Although not relevant to this particular question, the current version of Pages doesn't even open .rtf any longer, or export to that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can also display pictures in RTF files in the much lighter weight [Bean](http://www.bean-osx.com) which is actually based on TextEdit.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with .rtf files in this way is use Microsoft Word as that is really what the provider expects.

If you don't want to pay Microsoft then use OpenOffice software e.g. [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org) [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) which emulate Office

rtf has never had an official standard it is usually try to work out what Microsoft actually did.